Split the output of the dir command
I am trying to collect in an array the names of the files existing in a folder. These names can contain whitespaces. Let us say that I have a folder "test" with two files:
aaa bbb.txt
ccc ddd.txt

I would like to write a bash script to get the following output:
"aaa bbb.txt"
---
"ccc ddd.txt"
---

I wrote the following bash script:
#!/bin/bash

cd "test"

readarray -t my_array < <(dir -Q -1)

for elem in ${my_array[@]}
do
    echo "$elem"
    echo "---"
done

cd ..

Regrettably, I get the following output:
"aaa
---
bbb.txt"
---
"ccc
---
ddd.txt"
---

It seams that the whitespace acts as a delimiter, but the documentation of the command readarray says that the default delimiter is the newline. How can this be explained?

my_array=(*.txt)

I’m voting to close this question because ShellCheck finds the problem.

As Cyrus points out, x=(*.txt) avoids this. Don't run a program to do something the parser already handles. You could even get just the files with spaces - x=(*\ *.txt) which if you printf '%s\n' "${x[@]}" (quote the use of the array!) gives a b.txt and c d.txt.
Also a useful and related read: BashFAQ.

This is not related to the readarray command itself but the way how Bash is splitting the text when you iterate over my_array[@].

($@) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. In contexts where word splitting is performed, this expands each positional parameter to a separate word; if not within double quotes, these words are subject to word splitting.

see: source
To fix that you should put my_array[@] in quotes, so it doesn't treat space as delimiters there:
for elem in "${my_array[@]}"; do  # <-- QUOTES ADDED HERE
    echo "$elem"
    echo "---"
done


The wiki for tag bash tells you:

NOTE: Do not ask a bash question until you have copy/pasted your script into http://shellcheck.net and fixed all of the issues it tells you about.

If you had done that you would have found out:

Double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements.


I didn't even know there was a wiki for tags.

@Alcamtar even without finding the wiki, while writing your question, it is the description that pops up when you type bash into the tag  field

@Alcamtar Learn something new every day. ;)
